# python, numpy - in an array of string, compare element with previous for equality

Tags: python, numpy

Let's consider the following array:
`x = np.array(["john", "john", "ellis", "lambert", "john"])`

Is there a way to compare every element of the array to the previous and return a boolean array.
In the present example, the result would be `[True,False,False,False]`.

Is there any function (similar as `np.diff`) to achieve that?

Comment: Using slicing `x[1:] == x[:-1]`?

Comment: You should probably just be using a `list` for this...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with indexing:

```
array[:-1] == array[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first item in the list cannot be compared with a previous value and should likely default to `np.nan`.

To maintain the same shape as the original array:

```
>>> np.concatenate([np.array([np.nan]), x[:-1] == x[1:]])
array([ nan,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

The inclusion of `nan` changes to type to floats.

Answer (score 1):

Using indexing, you can do this with ease.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["john", "john", "ellis", "lambert", "john"])

print x[1:] == x[:-1]
```

The statement `x[1:] == x[:-1]` works because the `==` operand returns Boolean values, and in this case presented in an array due to the types of the two compared items.

`x[1:]` represents all the elements in the array except item 0, the first item, while `x[:-1]` represents all the elements in the array except the last item.